# Importing Tensorflow's Dataset class

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, and have installed tensorflow through pip, using `pip3 install tensorflow`. I now want to import and use the `Dataset` class, which is part of the `contrib.data` package. In various tutorials, this has simply been done using:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.contrib.data import Dataset
```

But this prints out:

```
ImportError: No module named 'tf'
```

I have also tried using this without the renaming of tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.contrib.data import Dataset
```

But this prints out:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dataset'
```

If I navigate to `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data`, then there are two directories (`__pycache__` and `python`), and two files (`_dataset_ops.so`, `__init__.py`). But I'm not sure where the `Dataset` class should be defined here, if at all...

So what should I do differently to enable me to import `Dataset`?

Answer (score 1):

`data` was moved out of `contrib` several Tensorflow versions ago. As far as I know a recent update completely removed most "standard" ops from `tf.contrib.data`. It now only contains "experimental"/volatile code. Simply use `tf.data.Dataset` instead.